# How to capture the change of Bluetooth in iOS development?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Can we be notified in those situations? When iPhone's Bluetooth is on or off. When iPhone connects to or disconnect to another device by Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager?changes=_5&language=objc) and add the [CBCentralManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate?changes=_5&language=objc) methods to see when a peripheral device is connected / disconnected.

`centralManagerDidUpdateState` will give information about your iOS device's bluetooth state.

`didConnectPeripheral` and `didDisconnectPeripheral` can be used for monitoring connected devices when you connect to the device within your app using `connect` on your centralManager (seen in example below).

If you know the identifier of the device you want to check for, you can use CBCentralManager's `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` to check the connection status for devices that are connected independent of your app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

  var centralManager:CBCentralManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
  }

  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
      centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("peripheral \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) connected")
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    print("peripheral \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) disconnected")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I've got another problem... I've tried your code, central.state is equal to CBManagerState, and function centralManagerDidUpdateState works. But didConnect and didDisconnect were never invoked, Why?

Comment: I have edited the code to connect to peripherals, those delegate methods are only invoked when your centralManager object connects or disconnects with a peripheral. If you want to see devices connected outside of your app, you need to know a service or uuid and use either of the `retrievePeripherals...` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. It seems that I should make further effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect bluetooth On/Off status change implementing  `CBCentralManagerDelegate` delegate of CoreBluetooth.

declare proparty like     `@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *bluetoothManager;`

And function like

```
 - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
    {
        NSLog(@"In status update function");
        switch(self.bluetoothManager.state)
        {
            case CBManagerStateResetting:
                _isBluetoothOn = NO;
                break;
            case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
                _isBluetoothOn = NO;
                break;
            case CBManagerStateUnauthorized:
                _isBluetoothOn = NO;
                break;
            case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
                _isBluetoothOn = NO;
                break;
            case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
                _isBluetoothOn = YES;
                break;
            default:
                _isBluetoothOn = NO;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ~